# System.out.println("hello"); error

Tags: java, system

This is my code

```
package aSSd;
import java.util.*;

public class New {

    System.out.println("hello");

}
```

the errors are:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Syntax error on token ".", @
>   expected after this token Ass.java    /Sdd/src/aSSd   line 6  Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete
>   MethodDeclaration Ass.java    /Sdd/src/aSSd   line 6  Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete
>   MethodHeaderName  Ass.java    /Sdd/src/aSSd   line 6  Java Problem
>
> Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete
>   QualifiedName Ass.java    /Sdd/src/aSSd   line 6  Java Problem

Comment: You class should be called `Ass` not `New`, it should follow the name of your filename. You `println` should also be enclosed by a method, presumably the `main` method

Comment: ...and put the print in the main or any other method. before that, start reading a java book, or tutorial. It is the best way to learn a programming language

Comment: Google for "Hello World in Java".

Comment: Please read a Java tutorial

Answer (score 9):

you can´t place statements just randomly in the class, you need to pack them into a method. example:

```
package aSSd; 

import java.util.*;

// Your java class should be called Ass, since your java File is called this way
public class Ass{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: You get half a point for the `main` method, so if you can fix the remaining error

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear,the main method is the entrance to a program.If you wish not to use the main method you can use the jar file. A jar file is used by other programs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using System.out.println () in a wrong way. Use it in some method like main method as illustrated below :

```
package aSSd;
import java.util.*;

public class New {

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("hello");
}

}
```

OR there is another way if you don`t want it from main method as :

```
package aSSd;
import java.util.*;

public class New {

static{
    System.out.println("hello");
}
 public static void main (String args [])
{}
}
```